# Why doesn't JavaScript get called when calling html file as a jQueryMobile dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

My index.html code works fine when I call reg.htm directly from JavaScript as window.open("reg.htm") (the JavaScript on the page is called and the AJAX and callback all works and my DB is updated).  However, when call REG.HTM with an  tag and put the jQueryMobile tag of data-rel="dialog" the file opens but doesn’t call any of the JavaScript.

index.html (works)
    
    
      
        Movie Reminder

```
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    .image    { position: relative; width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */ }
    .register { position: absolute; top: 250px; left: 0; width: 100%; padding-left: 106px;}
    .login    { position: absolute; top: 250px; left: 0; width: 100%; padding-left: 106px;}
    -->
    </style>

    <script language="Javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);         
        // Cordova is ready
        function onDeviceReady() 
            {
            var user = window.localStorage.getItem("user");
            alert ("Device Ready");
            if  (user == null) 
                window.open("reg.htm");
            else
                {
                var token = window.localStorage.getItem("token");
                if  (token == null) 
                    window.open("login.htm");
                else 
                    window.open("search.htm");                
                }
            }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            setTimeout("onDeviceReady()", 2000);
        });     
    </script>

</head>
<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0">
<div class="image">
    <img src="images/mov-rem-bkgd.jpg" alt=""  />
</div>        
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the code that calls using the  tag that doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Movie Reminder</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    .image    { position: relative; width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */ }
    .register { position: absolute; top: 250px; left: 0; width: 100%; padding-left: 106px;}
    .login    { position: absolute; top: 250px; left: 0; width: 100%; padding-left: 106px;}
    -->
    </style>

    <script language="Javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
            if  (window.localStorage.getItem("user") == null) 
                $('.register').show();
            else {
                if  (window.localStorage.getItem("token") == null) $('.login').show();
                else window.open("search.htm");                
                }
            }
        $(document).ready(function() { setTimeout("onDeviceReady()", 2000); });
    </script>

</head>
<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0">
<div class="image">
    <img src="images/mov-rem-bkgd.jpg" alt=""  />
    <div class="register">
        <a href="reg.htm" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">Register</a>
    </div>
    <div class="login" style="display:none">
        <a href="login.htm" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">Login</a>
    </div>
</div>        
</body>
</html>
```

If you create a simple reg.htm file that has the following code in it you'll see that the JavaScript is not called by index2.htm only by index1.htm.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert ("doc ready");
        $('.ui-btn-hidden').click(function(event) {
            $("#regform").submit(function(event) {   
                if  ($('.ui-btn-hidden').attr("value") == "Submit") 
                    {
                    alert ("inside submit");
                    var postData = "username=foo";
                    var urlStr = "http://www.fohost.co/mr/regUser/index.php?"; 
                    $.ajax({
                        url: urlStr,
                        data: encodeURI(postData),
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        success: doCallback
                        });
                    return false;
                    }
            });
        }); 
    });

    function doCallback(data) {
        alert("doCallback");
        if  (data.success == "true")
            window.open("login.htm");
        }
</script>
```

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: important to understand that `ready` has already occurred in main page and all your script in ajax content will fire immediately unlike when you load it as stand alone

Comment: I understand that ready has already occurred in the main page, but I'm trying to load a secondary page which does fire correctly when I call it from window.open but not from <a data-rel="dialog"> if I say data-ajax="false" I don't get a dialog - so back to the same issue

Comment: there are nunerous ways to set it up for code to fire properly when ajaxed into other page...if code is after all the html in the remote page is one, call it from main page instead in ajax success is another

Answer (score -1):

Read [Scripting Pages](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html). Applies to Dialogs as well.

Comment: Read it and it doesn't help with what I'm trying to do.